# Accessing tokens of a certain project in the embedded console of a Python IDE

Tags: python, ide, console

I'm currently using the [NINJA-IDE](http://ninja-ide.org/) for Python, but I expect a generic answer which is not specific to the NINJA-IDE (though don't give me an answer which is specific to Eclipse, Wing, NetBeans, PyCharm or any other-than-NINJA Python IDE. If the answer is specific be it specific to NINJA).

I would like to use the embedded interactive console which comes with my IDE so that I can quickly examine some objects, functions and classes. However, when trying to import a module of my project in the interactive console I receive an `ImportError`. The list `sys.path` includes the directory in which the module resides. I've tried changing the current working directory to the module's directory using `os.chdir()`, but I still get `ImportError`. I've also tried (inside NINJA-IDE) right clicking my project and selecting "Add this Project to the Python Console" as illustrated in the following screenshot. Still getting `ImportError`.

[image: Add this Project to the Python Console]

How do I access functions/methods/objects/classes of my project in the embedded console?

**EDIT:** *Specific details:*

- The project is named `movie_recommendations` and all the files reside in `C:\...\ninja projects\movie_recommendations`. The module's file I was talking about is `recommendations.py`. The file resides in `C:\...\ninja projects\movie_recommendations` among all the other files.
- The value of `sys.path` when typed in the embedded console is `['C:\\Program Files\\Ninja\\Ninja.exe', 'C:\\...\ninja projects\\movie_recommendations']`.
- The error message I get for `import recommendations` in the embedded console is `No module named recommendations`.

  [image: import recommendations]

Comment: Is the module part of a package? (In other words, is there an `__init__.py` alongside the module?)

Answer (score 0):

The current dir via os.chdir isnt what you need. The interpreter has already started at that point. If anything, you would import the sys module and add the path to the sys.path

But overall, you have to tell your IDE's project what the PYTHONPATH should be. I dont know that IDE but I assume it would be in the project settings.

Eclipse, for instance, has a section both in the general settings and project specific settings, for adding paths.

Comment: Thanks, but the path is already in `sys.path`. I've edited the question so it mentions it now.

Comment: Show the paths you have added. My guess is you added them at the wrong depth. And post the actually specific import error for reference.

Comment: added more details to the question.

Comment: Try creating an empty "__init__.py" file in the movie_recommendations location. And use forward slashes for paths if you are adding anything manually.